# Fabric / Crashlytics isn't reporting crashes on android

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have implemented fabric on my android app but it isn't reporting crashes on dashboard.

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // Add the Fabric Crashlytics plugin.
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I have added plugin and dependency in app.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

I also have added meta data in manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="true" />
```

And I am testing it by crashing the app by the below command

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();
```

Comment: try adding `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'` in your `app.gradle` it is recommended

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned in the question but I have already added `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'` in app.gradle

Comment: Have you followed all the steps from Firebase console?

Comment: add 
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}
in app gradle file

Comment: I recommend following this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

Comment: It takes some time for crash to be displayed on FCM console. Also try to crash app manually by using introducing a crash in your App.Use This:-

List<String> strings=new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("Random Text");
        strings.get(1);

Answer (score 0):

Please go to https://www.fabric.io/(your_organization)/android/apps/(your_app_id)
 . Check if it is not [migrated](https://www.fabric.io/firebase_migration) to the Firebase, then please migrate it.

[image]

It will appear on firebase crashylitic dashboard only if it is migrated. - https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/(your_project_id)/crashlytics

You can confirm it under project settings - integration https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/(your_project_id)/settings/integrations

[image: Fabric in Firebase integration]